# Identify paths between two nodes in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have two paths in a graph: A-B-C-D and A-B-E-F. I would like to assign identification numbers to those paths, i.e. A-B-C-D would be 1 and A-B-E-F would be 2.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like a persistent path ID? This isn't directly featured, but you can do it in a Query in Cypher.

If you want somthing persistent, you can always use an index, so create a `Relationship` index that would store the `Relationship`s of Path 1 under the key/value of Path:1.

EDIT: After getting more information, here's a use case using the index:

It would be up to you to define this in the Index. Here is what you do:

```
    Node a = db.createNode();
    Node b = db.createNode();
    Node c = db.createNode();
    Node d = db.createNode();
    Node e = db.createNode();
    Node f = db.createNode();

    Relationship aTob = a.createRelationshipTo(b, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("RELATIONSHIP"));
    Relationship bToc = b.createRelationshipTo(c, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("RELATIONSHIP"));
    Relationship cTod = c.createRelationshipTo(d, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("RELATIONSHIP"));

    Relationship bToe = b.createRelationshipTo(e, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("RELATIONSHIP"));
    Relationship eTof = e.createRelationshipTo(f, DynamicRelationshipType.withName("RELATIONSHIP"));

    Index<Relationship> relationshipIndex = db.index().forRelationships("PathIndex");
    String pathRId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String pathMId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    relationshipIndex.add(aTob, "PathId", pathRId);
    relationshipIndex.add(bToc, "PathId", pathRId);
    relationshipIndex.add(cTod, "PathId", pathRId);

    relationshipIndex.add(aTob, "PathId", pathMId);
    relationshipIndex.add(bToe, "PathId", pathMId);
    relationshipIndex.add(eTof, "PathId", pathMId);
```

Then when you want to find a path, you would search by the ID. You would be responsible for maintaining the Set Id in the index, here I use UUID, but you can use something more representative of your information. The relationships would not be in any repeatable order when returned from the Index.

Comment: Assuming for the path A-B-C-D relationships R=(R1,R2,R3), for the path  A-B-E-F relatioships M=(M1,M2,M3,M4), would a relationship index be able to hold the information about the R (i.e. three potentially distinct relationships)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "repeatable order"?

Comment: Meaning that when queried, you may get back `aTob`, `cTod` and `bToc`, which is not in the correct order. I believe that Lucene doesn't maintain insertion order, so you'll get back the relationships, however they may not be in the linear progression.

Comment: If I understand the notion of relation correctly, not having relations in the right order does not kill any important information. Please, confirm.

Also, can I do this in the web interface? There one may add a relationship index but then would have to assign the very index to a path (how?) and then, as you mentioned, assign a relationship index to the very path `relationshipIndex.add(aTob, "PathId", pathMId);`.

Comment: And one other question. You mentioned that I could be able to have the persistent path ids coded in Cypher? Could you show me an example of how to do that?  (I would also like to be able to change the value of the id).

Comment: The order may be important in certain use cases, but if you don't need it don't worry about it. The one in `Cypher` would not be persistent.

Comment: As for the web interface, if I create a graph in the neo4j web interface, will I be able to give a persistent id to an arbitrary path also in the web interface (through the use of the notion of a relation index)?

Comment: Well the web interface has many components. Do you mean the `RESTful` interface? Yes. The `Cypher` interface? Yes. If I remember correctly, at least for Version 1.8, you couldn't actually save to the index when creating nodes and relationships on just the Web interface though.